# Executing ASP.NET 1.1 Code within Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When the user clicks a certain LinkButton, I need to open a confirmation dialog with OK/Cancel. If the user hits OK, then I need to run a function from ASP.NET (something to update the database).

Something like the following...

**Javascript**

```
function openConfirm() {
     return window.confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?");
}
```

**ASP**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="viewPart" onClick="if(openConfirm() === true) <% SomeASPFunctionCall() %>;">
    Delete
</asp:LinkButton>
```

The catch is that my application is running ASP.NET 1.1, so any references to adding an `OnClientClick` to the control is irrelevant (because `OnClientClick` has been added for ASP 2.0). I have tried postbacks via __doPostBack and the __eventObject and __eventArguments, but those simply do not work or I can't figure it out.

How should I manage this combination of client-side/server-side interaction?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your linkButton has no ID, are you sure?

put an ID to it, let's imagine it's called `myLinkButton` (don't use this id please :D )

in the `Page_PreRender` put this code:

```
myLinkButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return window.confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?'");
```

it's pseudo code but should build and work also in .NET 1.1 I think, I am not using it since ages...

**Edit:** inside your grid, in the ItemDataBound or RowDataBound event depending on Framework and Grid version... put something like this:

```
private void myDataGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var myControl =  (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("myLinkButton");

        if(myControl != null)
        {
            myControl.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return window.confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the reason that the LinkButton has no ID is because it is in a repeater control (more specifically a TemplateColumn) within a DataGrid. Is there a way to address all the dynamically created link buttons like a CSS selector?

Comment: yes, you can still have an id also inside a TemplateItem anyway, editing my answer...